# Using Git with a a current Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, git

I use Windows XP and Eclipse Indigo. I have used TortoiseGit to pull and commit files 'til now with ease. How can I integrate my Java project files in Eclipse with the files that I pulled from Git?

After pulling the files from Git, I usually copy all the files manually from folder of Git to replace the files in my Eclipse project.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yeah!  move up to Juno and use EGit!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't move the files. Just pull the files to where you want your code to be located. Then use [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) to synch your files directly from Eclipse.

The same goes for any source control system (e.g. svn, cvs) and IDE (Netbeans, IntelliJ). Copying your files back and forth doesn't make sense.